# Laravel - Unable to access Sessions in render function of Exception Handler.php file

Tags: php, laravel, session, exception

Say for 404 Exception handling I'm trying to display a 404 page separately for admin and front pages based upon the user session, following is my render function of Handler.php file

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    echo Session::has('user.id');
    ...
    ...
}
```

But `Session::has('user.id')` always returning null value and I'm unable to decide if the user is actually logged-in.

In one of my old Laravel projects I have used the same logic and is successfully working, current project Laravel version is `5.2.45`

Thank you for your help.

Comment: can you post the method where you are passing `user.id` into session?

Comment: Why do you use session in this case and did you not forget to import Session?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the `auth()`-helper or `Auth`-Facade to retrieve information about the current logged in user and check if the user is logged in.

#### User ID

```
auth()->id();
Auth::id();
```

#### Check if user is logged in

```
auth()->check();
Auth::check();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user

Answer (score 0):

The problem you will have is at the point of a 404 error the `StartSession` middleware would not have run yet, so technically at the point the Exception is thrown the user information is not available yet.

One solution is perhaps to check specifically for endpoints like something containing an admin keyword `/admin/doesnotexist`, however is it limited as if your try just `/testing` the intention is not clear, is the users requesting a frontend or backend resource?

An alternative is something like:

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
        return redirect('/displaynotfound');
    }
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}

Route::get('/displaynotfound', function() {
    // Do what you need todo, as you will have access to
    // to the user.
    dd(auth()->user());
});
```